International Student in Canada who interned for 8mo in US - which country am I a tax resident of?
I have a bit of a strange tax residency situation:

I am a Citizen of India, but spent 0 days in India in 2023.

I am an international student in Canada, and spent 4 months of 2023 in Canada (studying on a student visa). I was a tax resident of Canada from 2019-2022, and will be in 2024.

The other 8 months of the year, I was on a J1 visa training/interning in the US for a US company.


Other details:

I have already filed my US tax return, and I know that I was not a tax resident in the US. Even though I passed the substantial presence test in the US (spent more than 183 days in the US), none of those days count since J1 makes me an "exempt-individual" (see here).

(accordingly, I did not have to pay Social Security / Medicaid taxes)


I am not sure if I am a tax resident of Canada.

Looking at the guidelines here, I did not own any property or car in Canada, and the 4 months I lived in Canada was only a temporary rental.

4 months is also less than 183 days.

I did, however, have active bank accounts/credit cards in Canada, and was still a student at a Canadian university.

Note that my J1 visa was contingent on me being a student at that Canadian university (the internship was part of my coursework, in a way).




I would obviously like to not be considered a non-resident of Canada because I can avoid paying taxes on my US income, but then I would technically not be a tax resident of any country.
So... am I a tax resident of Canada?

"because I can avoid paying taxes on my US income" If you were a resident of Canada, you would be able to claim a foreign tax credit on the tax paid to the US on that income, though you would still have some Canadian tax left if Canadian tax is higher than US tax.

You'd probably want to talk to a licensed tax advisor in Canada. My personal layman take is that you are in fact a tax resident in Canada for the whole year.
My reasoning:

Your absence was temporary, limited in time, and short
You have economical ties to Canada (bank account, etc).
You intended to return to Canada
Your center of life is there (you're an enrolled student, and you were required to remain as such, in a Canadian university)

In the guidelines you linked to, they discuss the concept of "factual resident", and bring temporary absence due to studies as one example for such a situation.
